# HornetQ low throughput when max-size-bytes reached

Tags: performance, hornetq, stomp, jms-topic

I have a simple configuration for testing: a fast C++ producer sending ~60 byte messages via Stomp to a topic, a slow consumer, and address-full-policy set to DROP.

The queue grows rapidly receiving several thousand messages per second until it reaches my max-size-bytes which amounts to about 300,000 messages.  HornetQ starts dropping messages as expected, but from then on is accepting only 3-4 messages per second from the producer.  What would cause that?  If it's dropping messages, shouldn't it be able to accept them full speed from the producer?